# ImageView covers extra white space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

[image]

Hi, I am creating a layout in android but the problem is that ImageView covers extra white space. I have added `scaleType`, `adjustViewBounds` but all in vain. Please help what can I do?

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibInitialStock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/initial_stock"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

but nothing is working.

Comment: does your image has extra padding ?

Comment: check image whether image has a white background?

Answer (score 0):

I think that white spaces are of your image,

try using

```
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or else try replacing your image